# Area inside a rectangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, area, rectangles

[image]

SEAMO 2016 paper E

I do not know how to start with this question and I have tried finding heights and bases of the triangle in terms of the sides of rectangle but i could not find the ideal pair

Comment: If you didn't have the diagonal AC, but instead cut the rectangle and the triangle EFG by a horizontal line going from the midpoint of AD to the midpoint of BC. What would the area of the coloured triangle be? How does it differ from the actual one in the question, i.e. is it larger smaller or the same?

Answer (score 2):

Let $AC\cap EG=\{H\}$ and $AC\cap GF=\{I\}$.

Thus, $$\frac{AH}{HC}=\frac{AE}{GC}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{2}{3},$$
Which says that $$AH=\frac{2}{5}AC.$$
Also,
$$\frac{CI}{IA}=\frac{CG}{AF}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{3}{4},$$
Which says that $$CI=\frac{3}{7}AC.$$
Thus, $$HI=AC\left(1-\frac{3}{7}-\frac{2}{5}\right)=\frac{6}{35}AC,$$
which says
$$\frac{S_{\Delta IHG}}{S_{\Delta ADC}}=\frac{6}{35}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{35}$$ and
$$S_{\Delta IHG}=\frac{3}{70}S_{ABCD}=1.5.$$

Comment: what do you call the property in which you used for the first equation?

Comment: @SuperMage1 Because $\Delta AEH\sim\Delta CGH$.

Answer (score 0):

EFG is an isoceles triangle that has an area 1/6 the area of the whole rectangle

The green shaded area has the equivalent area to a triangle that is the top half of the triangle EFG. (Imagine a line horizontally between the midpoints of EG and EF, just as much green above as below the line)

The top half of an isoceles triangle has 1/4 the area of the whole

Therefore the area of the green shaded is 1/24 the are of the whole.

Assuming the total area is 36 then the shaded ares is 1.5

If the total area is 35 then maybe I got this wrong or its none of the above

Comment: When you put a line through the midpoints of $EG$ and $EF$ you cut a small triangle off the dark green part of $\triangle EFG$ and another small triangle off the lighter part. The small dark triangle is larger than the small light triangle. You incorrectly assumed the areas are the same, and that's how you get an incorrect result.